# wxPython macOS Dark Mode support and pyinstaller

Tags: macos, wxpython, pyinstaller

When running my `wxPython` script invoking it with `python3 ./run.py` on the command line, it uses dark mode (the window title bar is drawn dark). Freezing this script with `pyinstaller` and launching the built app bundle, dark mode is ignored (title bar is light).

That's the command to freeze the script:

```
pyinstaller run.py --onefile --noconsole
```

The example source:

```
import wx
class App(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = wx.App(False)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Window")
        wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="Hello World!", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp = App()
    myapp.app.MainLoop()
```

My software versions:
macOS 10.14.6.
Python: 3.7.3.
wxPython: 4.0.7
wxWidgets: 3.0.5
pyinstaller: 3.5

Comment: This is happening with PyQt5 as well. The problem is likely related more to pyinstaller than to wxPython.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `'NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance': 'No'` to your PyInstaller `.spec` file:

```py
app = BUNDLE(exe,
    ...
    name=...,
    icon=...,
    info_plist={
        ...
        'NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance': 'No'
    },
    bundle_identifier=None)
```

and the resulting PyInstaller created .app file should launch OK in dark mode.

I just confirmed this works with one of my wxPython apps [Pynsource](https://github.com/abulka/pynsource), using the prerelease `wxPython==4.1.0a1.dev4616+ef1edacc` - more info in this [Phoenix issue](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1132).